# Property Value is not appear in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My View Code

```
<div class="col-sm-4"  id="AppCheckActiveOrNot">
            @foreach (var item in module1List)
            {

                string checkedAccess = "";

                if (Model.ModuleDetailAccess != null)
                {
                    if (Model.ModuleDetailAccess.Count > 0)
                    {

                        var getAccess = Model.ModuleDetailAccess.Where(m => m.ModuleID == item.ModuleID && m.ParentModuleID == module1.ModuleID && m.RoleID == 0 && m.isApp == 1 && m.isActive == 1 && m.UserID == UserID).ToList();

                        if (getAccess.Count > 0)
                        {
                            checkedAccess = "checked";
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">

                                <input type="checkbox" id=@string.Format("childapp{0}{1}", module1.ModuleID, item.ModuleID) name=@string.Format("childapp{0}", module1.ModuleID) value="@item.ModuleID" @checkedAccess onchange="Test(this)"/>
                                <label for=@string.Format("childapp{0}{1}", module1.ModuleID, item.ModuleID)>@item.ModuleDesc</label>
                                <input type="text" name=@string.Format("hideapp{0}", item.ModuleID) value="1" />

                            </div>
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">

                                <input type="checkbox" id=@string.Format("childapp{0}{1}", module1.ModuleID, item.ModuleID) name=@string.Format("childapp{0}", module1.ModuleID) value="@item.ModuleID" @checkedAccess onchange="Test(this)" />
                                <label for=@string.Format("childapp{0}{1}",module1.ModuleID, item.ModuleID)>@item.ModuleDesc</label>
                                <input type="text" name=@string.Format("hideapp{0}", item.ModuleID) value="0" />

                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
```

Shortly, i want to change the value of **input type="text"** when my checkbox onChange. If it is change to checked, the value of input type="text" will be 1.

Here is my javascript

```
 function Test(src)
   {
       var Fields = $('#AppCheckActiveOrNot').find(src);
       var textbox = $('#AppCheckActiveOrNot').find('input[type=text]');



       for (a = 0; a < Fields.length; a++)
       {
           if (Fields[a].checked) {

                  console.log(textbox[a])
           }

           else {
               console.log(textbox[a])
           }
       }


   }
```

So, the problem is when i try to set the value of input type="text", the property of .value is not appear. There is only .val , when i use .val, it's return Uncaught Type Error textbox[a].val is not a function in console.
So i got stuck here, thanks before for spending your time to answer this.

Comment: The value of a checkbox is the property `checked`, not `val` or `value`

Comment: No sir, it's for checking if the checkbox checked or not. Because, the stored data of the checkbox is true in database. So i need to change the value of  input type text when checkbox is checked

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="one" />
```

To change the text of the textbox, here is how to do it with pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('one').value = 'New Value';
```

With JQuery:

```
$('#one').val('JQuery');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkr2j67o/1/)

Comment: In my case, the checkbox and input text is looped. So if checkbox[0] checked, the text input[0]'s value will be 1. I can't set the input value. Because can't give the property of value.

Comment: So you cannot get the checkbox's value?